# ER Diagram is this possible with recursion

Tags: database-design, erd

I am trying to get the hang of doing ER Diagrams to model something and most examples for recursion are something like person is Manager of kind of thing which is clear.

But if I am not sure if the following is possible to model in ER:

I have an Entity "*Chapters*" ( with an id, title, wordcount ) which itself can contain none or N other chapters as subchapters (and this can repeat). I did this recursion.

But can I:

a) show the sequence of subchapters in the ER
b) model that the wordcount of a chapter includes those of its subchapters?

Or are these things that shouldnt be considered in an ER diagram but at a later stage?

Comment: Hi. Please give examples of what designs you mean. PS What is your reference for the version of the ERM (entity-realtionship model) you are using? It gives some notation for designs. That's all that method can say. (Including limiting what designs it can produce.) ER is a thin unnecessary restrictive layer on the RM (relational model). In the RM queries can express arbitrary constraints. And then there are the pseudo-ER methods. PS Your use of "recursion" is vague & strange. Definitions/expressions are recursive; relationships just are--as represented by tables in the RM & the ERM.

Comment: Re giving designs: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ER diagrams aren't very good for showing most kinds of dependencies and constraints. If those things are shown at all in an ER diagram then they are usually added as textual annotations.

In UML modelling there is a specific notation for "aggregation", e.g. a sub-chapter forming part of a chapter. I think it's debatable how useful this is in most situations. UML modellers tend to be a bit inconsistent in their use of association/aggregation/composition in my experience. Here's an example UML diagram showing aggregation:

[image]

If you are interested in modelling rules in more detail then Object Role Modelling is quite a powerful tool. ORM's ring constraint notation for acyclic, subset constraints could represent your chapter and sub-chapter situation quite well.

The problem with trying to represent too many things graphically is that the more complex your diagrams become the more difficult they are to comprehend. Sometimes a sentence or two can do the job better.